# E334: Menu not found: Window.Minimize

Tags: vimrc, macvim, error

I'm using MacVim installed with `brew` and everything works pretty fine, but (and there always is a "but") when I launch it as `mvim` from the terminal, it says

```
Error detected while processing /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-98/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/menu.vim:
line 1222:
E334: Menu not found: Window.Minimize
```

I'm pretty sure that the problem is in my `.vimrc` or my plugins, but I don't know how to find the one responsible.

What can I do to fix this? It's just a bit annoying.

Here is my `.vimrc` (and it is in a bit of mess):

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

"=====================================================
" Vundle settings
"=====================================================
" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'      " let Vundle manage Vundle, required

"---------=== Code/project navigation ===-------------
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'            " Project and file navigation
Plugin 'majutsushi/tagbar'              " Class/module browser

"------------------=== Other ===----------------------
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'              " Lean & mean status/tabline for vim
Plugin 'fisadev/FixedTaskList.vim'      " Pending tasks list
Plugin 'rosenfeld/conque-term'          " Consoles as buffers
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'     " Parentheses, brackets, quotes, XML tags, and more

"--------------=== Snippets support ===---------------
Plugin 'garbas/vim-snipmate'        " Snippets manager
Plugin 'MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils'   " dependencies #1
Plugin 'tomtom/tlib_vim'        " dependencies #2
Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'     " snippets repo

"---------------=== Languages support ===-------------
" --- Python ---
Plugin 'klen/python-mode'           " Python mode (docs, refactor, lints, highlighting, run and ipdb and more)
"Plugin 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'      " Jedi-vim autocomplete plugin
"Plugin 'mitsuhiko/vim-jinja'       " Jinja support for vim
Plugin 'mitsuhiko/vim-python-combined'  " Combined Python 2/3 for Vim

call vundle#end()                   " required
filetype on
filetype plugin on
filetype plugin indent on

"=====================================================
" General settings
"=====================================================
set backspace=indent,eol,start
aunmenu Help.
aunmenu Window.
let no_buffers_menu=1
set mousemodel=popup

set ruler
set completeopt-=preview
set gcr=a:blinkon0
if has("gui_running")
  set cursorline
endif
set ttyfast

" ???????? ????????? ????
syntax on
if has("gui_running")
" GUI? ???????????? ???? ? ?????? ????
  set lines=50 columns=125
  colorscheme colorsbox-material "monokai
" ???????????????? ??? ??????, ???? ??????, ????? NERDTree/TagBar ????????????? ???????????? ??? ??????? vim
" autocmd vimenter * TagbarToggle
" autocmd vimenter * NERDTree
" autocmd vimenter * if !argc() | NERDTree | endif

" ?? ???? vim?
set guifont=LiterationMonoPowerline:h11
set fuoptions=maxvert,maxhorz
endif

tab sball
set switchbuf=useopen

" ????????? ??????? ? ???????
set visualbell t_vb= 
set novisualbell       

set enc=utf-8        " utf-8 ?? ??????? ? ??????
set ls=2             " ?????? ?????????? ?????????
set incsearch        " ???????????????? ?????
set hlsearch         " ????????? ??????????? ??????
set nu               " ?????????? ?????? ?????
set scrolloff=5      " 5 ????? ??? ??????? ?? ???

" ????????? ?????? ? ????-?????
set nobackup         " no backup files
set nowritebackup    " only in case you don't want a backup file while editing
set noswapfile       " no swap files

" ?????? ????????
"set guioptions-=m   " ????
set guioptions-=T    " ??????
"set guioptions-=r   "  ??????????

" ????????? ?? Tab
set smarttab
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=0
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4

"  ??? ???????? ?? ??????? ? 80 ???????? ? Ruby/Python/js/C/C++ ???????????? ?? ?????? ???? ?????
augroup vimrc_autocmds
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType ruby,python,javascript,c,cpp highlight Excess ctermbg=DarkGrey guibg=Black
    autocmd FileType ruby,python,javascript match Excess /\%80v.*/
    autocmd FileType c,cpp match Excess /\%110v.*/
    autocmd FileType ruby,python,javascript,c,cpp set nowrap
augroup END

" ????????? ??????? ? ??????????? SnipMate
let g:snippets_dir = "~/.vim/vim-snippets/snippets"

" ????????? Vim-Airline
set laststatus=2
let g:airline_theme='badwolf'
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#formatter = 'unique_tail'

" TagBar ?????????
map <F4> :TagbarToggle<CR>
let g:tagbar_autofocus = 0 " ????????? ?? Tagbar ??? ????????

" NerdTree ?????????
" ???????? NERDTree ?? F3
map <F3> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
"????????????? ????? ? ????????????
let NERDTreeIgnore=['\~$', '\.pyc$', '\.pyo$', '\.class$', 'pip-log\.txt$', '\.o$']  

" TaskList ?????????
map <F2> :TaskList<CR>     " ?????????? ?????? ?????? ?? F2

" ?????? ?????????
map <C-q> :bd<CR>      " CTRL+Q - ??????? ??????? ??????

"=====================================================
" Python-mode settings
"=====================================================
" ????????? ??????????? ?? ???? (? ??? ?????? ???? ???????????? jedi-vim)
"let g:pymode_rope = 0
"let g:pymode_rope_completion = 0
"let g:pymode_rope_complete_on_dot = 0

" ????????????
let g:pymode_doc = 0
let g:pymode_doc_key = 'K'
" ???????? ????
let g:pymode_lint = 1
let g:pymode_lint_checker = "pyflakes,pep8"
let g:pymode_lint_ignore="E501,W601,C0110"
" ??????? ???? ????? ??????????
let g:pymode_lint_write = 1

" ????????? virtualenv
let g:pymode_virtualenv = 1

" ????????? breakpoints
let g:pymode_breakpoint = 1
let g:pymode_breakpoint_key = '<leader>b'

" ?????????? ??????????
let g:pymode_syntax = 1
let g:pymode_syntax_all = 1
let g:pymode_syntax_indent_errors = g:pymode_syntax_all
let g:pymode_syntax_space_errors = g:pymode_syntax_all

" ????????? autofold ?? ????
let g:pymode_folding = 0

" ??????????? ????????? ???
let g:pymode_run = 0

" Disable choose first function/method at autocomplete
let g:jedi#popup_select_first = 0

let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

"=====================================================
" Languages support
"=====================================================
" --- Python ---
"autocmd FileType python set completeopt-=preview " ????????????????, ? ??????, ???? ?? ????, ????? jedi-vim ????????? ???????????? ?? ??????/??????
autocmd FileType python setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 tabstop=8
\ formatoptions+=croq softtabstop=4 smartindent
\ cinwords=if,elif,else,for,while,try,except,finally,def,class,with
autocmd FileType pyrex setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 tabstop=8 softtabstop=4 smartindent cinwords=if,elif,else,for,while,try,except,finally,def,class,with

" --- template language support (SGML / XML too) ---
autocmd FileType html,xhtml,xml,htmldjango,htmljinja,eruby,mako setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2 softtabstop=2
autocmd bufnewfile,bufread *.rhtml setlocal ft=eruby
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.mako setlocal ft=mako
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.tmpl setlocal ft=htmljinja
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.py_tmpl setlocal ft=python
let html_no_rendering=1
let g:closetag_default_xml=1
let g:sparkupNextMapping='<c-l>'
autocmd FileType html,htmldjango,htmljinja,eruby,mako let b:closetag_html_style=1
autocmd FileType html,xhtml,xml,htmldjango,htmljinja,eruby,mako source ~/.vim/scripts/closetag.vim

" --- LaTeX ---
" REQUIRED. This makes vim invoke Latex-Suite when you open a tex file.
filetype plugin on

" IMPORTANT: grep will sometimes skip displaying the file name if you
" search in a singe file. This will confuse Latex-Suite. Set your grep
" program to always generate a file-name.
set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*

" OPTIONAL: This enables automatic indentation as you type.
filetype indent on

" OPTIONAL: Starting with Vim 7, the filetype of empty .tex files defaults to
" 'plaintex' instead of 'tex', which results in vim-latex not being loaded.
" The following changes the default filetype back to 'tex':
let g:tex_flavor='latex'

" --- Keyboard ---
let g:XkbSwitchEnabled = 1
let g:XkbSwitchIMappingsSkipFt = ['tex']
let g:XkbSwitchIMappings = ['ru']
```

Comment: According to [`:h E334`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui.html#E334) I'm wondering if your problem isn't related to the lines  45-46 of your `.vimrc`. I'm not really familiar with the `aunmenu` option so I can't really help but maybe you should head this way. Also see [this question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841) about how to debug your `.vimrc`

Comment: Why do you remove those menus?

Comment: I didn't even know about these lines; my `.vimrc` is a huge patchwork of examples and I do not understand everything in there. @statox, if you put this as an answer, I will accept it --- deleting these lines fixed my problem and doesn't seem to have broken anything

Comment: @Akiiino: If you're a new comer to Vim please don't use stuff you don't understand in your `.vimrc`: this question is the perfect example of why you shouldn't. Start with an empty `.vimrc` and built your own vim: you'll learn much more about this wonderful editor and you will not loose time debug options that you don't understand. And when you'll have issues about stuff you've done yourself it will be much easier for us to help you ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Important note** As I mentioned it in the comments when you begin to use Vim the best you can do is to start with an emtpy `.vimrc`. From this you'll be able to build your own configuration which really suits your needs.

There are a [lot](https://pragprog.com/book/dnvim/practical-vim) [of](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) [resources](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/63/how-can-a-complete-beginner-learn-vim-using-just-vim-itself) to help you beginning with Vim.

So **don't copy stuff you don't understand in your `.vimrc`** it I'll only cause trouble and lot of hard debugging time.

Also @Carpetsmoker did a great guide about [how to debug your `.vimrc`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841). You'll need it, trust me ;-)

---

**Now about your particular problem**

You have an error `E334: Menu not found: Window.Minimize`. Conveniently Vim has a great help system so just type [`:h E334`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui.html#E334) to get an idea of what your problem comes from.

Here it is related to the settings of the menus in your GUI. If you scrolldown in the help page you'll see mentions of `aunmenu` and `guioptions` options.

In your `.vimrc` the lines 45 and 46 use these options to remove the help menu and the window menu in all modes. Then you know that these lines are creating a problem.